# With Firebase, I'd like to get data asynchronously and show on TableView but some of data are duplicated on TableView

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, closures

With Firebase, I'd like to get data asynchronously, and then show it on TableView, but some of data are duplicated on TableView. I think it's because I use closure in For statement but I'm not sure where I should call it instead.

I tried to call setDataToArray in Dispatchqueue.main.async but it doesn"t work.

```
Class PostTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    var postArray: [Post] = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SVProgressHUD.show()
        configureTableview()
        setDataToArray()
    }

    func setDataToArray() {

        retrievePost() { (posts) in

            print(posts!)

            for post in posts! {

                self.postArray.append(post)

            }

            print(self.postArray)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        }
    }

    func retrievePost(completion: @escaping ([Post]?) -> Void) {

        var posts = [Post]()
        let postsColRef = db.collection("posts").order(by: "createdAt")

        postsColRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Document data: \(error)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let userId = data["userId"] as? String
                    let postImage = data["postImageURL"] as? String
                    let postText = data["postText"] as? String
                    let createdAt = data["createdAt"] as? String
                    let numberOfLike = data["numberOfLike"] as? Int
                    let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(userId!)

                    docRef.getDocument() { (document, error) in
                        if let document = document, document.exists {

                            let data = document.data()!
                            let userName = data["userName"] as? String
                            let userImage = data["userImageURL"] as? String

                            let post = Post(
                                userId: userId!,
                                userName: userName!,
                                userImageURL: userImage!,
                                postImageURL: postImage!,
                                postText: postText!,
                                createdAt: createdAt!,
                                numberOfLike: numberOfLike!)

                            print(post)
                            posts.append(post)
                            completion(posts)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeToChooseImage", sender: nil)

    }



    }


    extension PostTableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return postArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

        let post = postArray[indexPath.row]

        let postImageURL = URL(string: post.postImageURL)

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: postImageURL!)
            cell.postImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }catch let err {
            print("Error : \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let userImageURL = URL(string: post.userImageURL)

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: userImageURL!)
            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }catch let err {
            print("Error : \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }

        cell.postText.text = post.postText

        cell.userName.text = post.userName

        cell.createdAt.text = post.createdAt

        cell.postLikeButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(post.numberOfLike) Likes"

        return cell
    }

}
```

I guess where I call "completion(posts)" is wrong.
Where should I call it instead?

Comment: Hello thatnaoki. What's the minimal amount of code you can still reproduce the error with? If you find that point, you'll likely have the answer. If not, posting the simplified code here will likely garner more responses. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try moving `completion(posts)` outside of the `For` loop? Your completion closure expects an array of posts, but you are calling the completion closure each time during the loop.

Comment: @Kato Thank you very much for your advice! Right now, the problem has been solved.

Comment: @DennisW. Thank you very much! I tried it and now it"s working.